# Android library project can not be launched

Tags: android, project

I downloaded one project from web. It includes two folders. One is project and another is library. When I first time imported both and set proper path for library, it runs properly. But now after deleting that project, and importing again, it shows error that it is library project. I repeated the same procedure that I done first time. What to do. [image]

Comment: It is because you are launching library project. Library project are supporting packages which helps to build application, its not an application that will run/launch.

Comment: Also, sometimes people release library projects with a runnable test/example project that is runnable.

Comment: runnable test/example project: Hey stealth let me know this statement means

Comment: hotveryspicy: But first time it runs properly. Then how it is library project

Comment: I got my answer. Problem is solved

Comment: care to share with the class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you run your project as library,

```
1. Right click on your project
2. Go to the property
3. Select Android from left section
4. The **is_library** check-box should be Unselected
5. Click on apply button
6. Click on OK button
```

And at last run your project.

It's working for me. Try it.